# Window opened with showDialog, TextBlock is showing underneath window instead of text

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, showdialog

I have this wierd wpf problem.
I have a window (full screennm) with an Image, looks like this:
[image]

I open a new window with Showdialog uppon this window, which is not full screen (looks like a popup, but its a window). the code is like this:

```
 Window next;  next = new PasswordVerification();
 next.Owner = this;
  next.ShowDialog();
```

on the open window I use this to center the "popup":

```
 this.Left = this.Owner.Left + (this.Owner.Width - this.ActualWidth) / 2;
        this.Top = this.Owner.Top + (this.Owner.Height - this.ActualHeight) / 2;
        this.Topmost = true;
```

I get something like this ( i cropped it, the window is slight bigger):
[image]

Where the textblock is defined like this:

```
            <Rectangle Name="errorBorder" Fill="#34FF0000" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" RadiusX="13" RadiusY="13" Stroke="#FFB80005" Visibility="Visible" Margin="43,195,78,203" />
        <TextBlock Name="error" Text="TextBlock" Margin="49,195,91,205" FontSize="20" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFB80000" Visibility="Visible" />
```

Now I have a button, that does this:

```
 error.Text = "blabla";
```

But instead of what I expected (that the Text will change) I get this wierd stuff:
[image]
As you can see, The image from the rear window is sligtly shown, instead of my textBlock!

What is going on here??Please Help!

The PopUp XAML:

```
<Window ...  Width="1000" Height="700"  AllowsTransparency="True" 
WindowStyle="None" 
Background="#00000000"/>
<Border  Style="{StaticResource SmallScreenBorderStyle}" CornerRadius="23" Padding="2" Margin="153.66,117.992,153.661,117.992" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height">
 <!-- Use a VisualBrush of 'mask' as the opacity mask -->
        <Grid.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=mask}"/>
        </Grid.OpacityMask>
  <!-- Rounded mask (stretches to fill Grid) to make grid rounded corners -->
        <Border x:Name="mask" CornerRadius="20" Margin="2,5,-1,-5" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" Style="{StaticResource MaskBorderStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Just made a simple app trying to reproduce your behavior, but it worked as expected. Judging from the pictures I assume that the PasswordVerification window has some modifications making it look like a popup. Can you show those? Or switch them off to narrow the issue?

Comment: Yes. I edit my post, I will add some xaml

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions:
1) Remove your code to open window at center of owner, just use this in your `Window` XAML:

```
<Window ....
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
```

2) Shorten your calling method:

```
Window next = new PasswordVerification {Owner = this};
next.ShowDialog();
```

3) Put your `Rectangle` and `TextBlock` in `<StackPanel>` or another container. Probably the problem that these controls overlaps because lives inside Grid.

Comment: 1 is missing code. 2 is not neccasry since my code is a bit longer, I simplified it here for convinience. I will try 3

Comment: Ah, see. Looks like some problem in Visual tree. Did you try to remove AllowsTransparency="True" from Window XAML or  this.Topmost = true from code-behind(I think  it is not necessary because modal dialog already at top).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try setting the `Visible` property to false on your your main form, and then setting it back to true after your `ShowDialog`?